# How to record RTE protocol in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I can able to record mainframe application which contains RTE protocol in Load Runner with terminal window.I do not know how to record the same in J-meter.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately JMeter isn't capable of recording RTE protocol.

The closest tool JMeter offers is [TCP Sampler](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/268778-how-to-send-control-characters-using-the-jmeter-tc) but you'll have to figure out what to send via a sniffer tool.

The most powerful free sniffer is [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/%E2%80%8E).

See [Telnet 3270](http://wiki.wireshark.org/TN3270) Wireshark wiki page for reference.

---

UPD August 2018: Although you cannot record RTE protocol in JMeter it is now possible to create a load test using [JMeter RTE Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-jmeter-mainframe-testing-with-the-new-rte-plugin) so you will be able to simulate connection events, sending keys, etc.